# Python upgrade to 2.7.2 from 2.4.x leads to yum module missing

Tags: centos, python, yum

yum was working fine till I upgraded Python for the sake of django in my VPS.

It throws exactly this error:

> There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
>   required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
>
> No module named yum
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or
>   verify that the module is installed correctly.
>
> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the current version of Python, which is:
>   2.7.2 (default, Mar  7 2012, 08:41:42)
>   [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)]
>
> If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
>   the yum faq at:  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq

Why is this happening?

Does it mean I have to reinstall yum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never upgrade the system Python, because there are other tools (like yum!) that depend on it.  You should always install a newer Python alongside the system Python, and you should make sure that `/usr/bin/python` points to the system Python.

You should probably restore the original version of Python (you should be able to grab this from a CentOS mirror and install it using the `rpm` command), and then install a newer version of Python in an alternate location.

You may also need to re-install `yum`.

Comment: I used to alter python SRPM from Fedora for this sake, replacing all references to "python" with "python<version>" (it was python25 in my case) so there'd be no intersecting files/provisions/requirements.